# Unable to connect to neo4j VM on the network via Neo4jDesktop

Tags: neo4j, cypher, database-connection

I downloaded the neo4j OVA from bitnami and spun it up on my VSphere Server. The installed version of Neo4j on this prepackaged VM is 5.13 Community Edition.

It has a static IP address (192.168.1.6)

I am able to connect via SSH, I can ping it, and everything's fine here

The neo4j.conf was altered like this:

```
server.default_listen_adress = 0.0.0.0
server.default_advertised_adress = 192.168.1.6
server.bolt.enabled=true
server.bolt.list_adress=:7687
server.bolt.advertised_adress=:7687
server.http.enabled=true
server.http.listen_adress=:7474
server.http.advertised_adressadress=:7474
```

The `sudo neo4j-admin server validate-config` does not show any errors

I am able to connect to the graph from within the server VM using `cyper-shell -a localhost -u neo4j -p myPassword`, so I know the user credentials work.

The `ss -tulpn` shows
|netid|state|Local Address:Port|Peer Address:Port|
|:----|:----|:-----------------|:----------------|
|tcp|LISTEN|*:7687|* : *|
|tcp|LISTEN|*:7474|* : *|

But whatever I try to use to connect this server as a remote connection within the Neo4j Desktop Client, I can't get a connection. Every possible combination of port, and protocol (neo4j, bolt, neo4j+s, etc.) just yields "Unable to establish remote connection: ServiceUnavailable".

What am I doing wrong? Is it just not possible to connect to a community edition using the Desktop app?